# random number generator in boost.python

Tags: random, boost-python

How can I use the same random number generator in my "Python with numpy" code as my C++0x code?

I am currently using

```
std::ranlux64_base_01
```

in C++ and

```
numpy.random.RandomState(10)
```

in Python.

I exposed C++'s random number generator:

```
typedef std::ranlux64_base_01 RNG;
RNG g_rng;

...

class_<RNG>("RNG");
scope().attr("g_rng") = g_rng;
```

How do I use it with Python's methods that take a numpy.random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways: 
the first is to use pythons random number generator from c++. It will probably look something like this:

```
boost::python::object randmod = boost::python::import("numpy.random")
boost::python::object randfunc = randmod.attr("RandomState")
randfunc(10)
```

The second is to wrap and expose the c++ function so that it can be used from python. The code for this is left an an exercise for the student.

Edit:
Once you have exported the c++ function you would have to make a python object that mimics the interface of numpy.random.RandomState using the c++ function for it's random bits. This is probably more work then you want to do. I have not used numpy, but from the docs it looks like the RandomState object is not-trivial.